# C++ passing a pointer multiple times by reference then modifying it. How can I make it work?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, pass-by-reference

The following is a small scale example of the problem I am facing. In the example below I use int pointers but in my own code I am really using a pointer to another class.

I do need/want to be able to pass multiple pointers to the same method and I do not really want to write a specific method for each pointer. 
When I run the code, of course, I do not get the expected results.

I think I have narrowed down the problem but am not sure how to fix it. Since everything in C++ is pass by value, the pointers that I am passing around need to be pass by reference. I did try changing my methods to call by reference like this in the below method:

```
int** getIntPointer() {return &p1;}
```

`void initializeP1(int **&ip,int n)` and `void initializeP1(int **ip,int n)`

But nothing seems to be working.

Does anyone have a clue how to fix this?

Thank you

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test {
  private:
    int *p1;   
    int *p2;
    int sizeP1;
    int sizeP2;   
  public:
    int** getIntPointer() {return &p1;}
    void initializeP1(int **&ip,int n){
        sizeP1=n; 
        *ip=new int[n];

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            *ip[i]=i;         
    }  
    void printP1() {
        for(int i=0;i<sizeP1;i++)
            cout<<p1[i]<<" "; 
    }
};

int main() {
    Test t;
    int** p = t.getIntPointer();
    t.initializeP1(*&p,10);
    t.printP1(); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you need the hot-address of a private member variable pointer exposed to any outside caller? This pretty much violates every reasonable conception of implementation and information hiding regarding OOP. A const-address or const-reference I can muster, but a hot-pointer to pointer to ... something? Perhaps a little more insight to the problem being address may shed light on this.

Comment: Dont do this! <int **&ip> try it like this <int **ip>    
You're just using what ip points to.

Comment: On <*&p> the asterisk and the ampersand '&' cancel each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
*ip[i]=i;
```

The `[]` operator has higher precedence than the `*` operator, so that line is equivilent to this:

```
*(ip[i])=i;
```

You need to change it to this instead:

```
(*ip)[i]=i;
```

Comment: You sir are a genius! I did not even have the concept of operator precedence. I am a Java person.. I guess I need to find a website to study operator precedence. Any suggestions?

Comment: See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 0):

also, why do you call the function `initializeP1` but use `**ip`? do it like

```
 void initializeP1(int n){
    sizeP1=n;
    p1=new int[sizeP1];
    for(int i=0;i<sizeP1;i++)
         p1[i]=i;
 }
```

would have worked in the first placed that way (much less `*`'s and so on :)